# Detailed explanation of Perlin Noise algorithmic complexity

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics

I am doing a project in analysis of algorithm and I have been looking all over for something more complex than Perlin Noise is $O(n \cdot 2^n)$ because of the doubling in $n$ dimensions and array operations. Anyone know where there is more information? I have another month before our group gives the presentation.

Comment: Some context is missing here. What problem are you trying to solve? What is *Perlin Noise*?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus If you do not know what Perlin Noise is, it seems a response is inappropriate. Perlin Noise was designed by Ken Perlin in the 1980s. It is used in a wide variety of computer graphics. One of the more well known uses is in Minecraft terrain generation. Simply put Perlin Noise is interpolated noise.

Comment: It is possible that even people not aware of Perlin Noise could help you. If you don’t want their help, then there is indeed no reason to explain any further.